# Unity File Generate

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I want to create an app in Unity for Android. I want the app to have a button where you can add comments and those will be saved in a .txt file and a "View Comment" button where the comments are shown on a canvas from the .txt file.

When I run it on Unity game, it works properly with manually created .txt files in the directory. **However**, when the app is built on Mobile I do not know if I have those .txt files generated or how to generate them.

This is the code for viewing comments:

```
public Text exit_text=null;

public void ViewComment()
{
    string readText = File.ReadAllText("sunflowercomments.txt");
    exit_text.text = readText;
}
```

And this is the code for writing the comments:

```
public InputField input_text;

public void AddComment()
{
    string readText = File.ReadAllText("sunflowercomments.txt");
    string text = input_text.text;
    string new_string = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", readText, System.Environment.NewLine, text);

    File.WriteAllText("sunflowercomments.txt", new_string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard answering your question because you aren't really showing how/where you create the file. However, you should be able to save to a .txt-file on android, you just need to be sure you have proper write access to the path you are trying to write to.